# iOS: uitableview redraw objects on first cell to bottom cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

i have a uitableview with custom cells.. with normal code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    DDMainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[DDMainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    }
}
```

the problem is when i select one cell i add progress bar on the cell that download data online.. but when i Scroll down i find that every 10 cells have the same progress bar .. how can i prevent this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
dataarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
indexarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
mytableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
mytableview.dataSource=self;
mytableview.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:mytableview];
for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
    [dataarr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
 return [dataarr count];
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}
cell.textLabel.text=[dataarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIActivityIndicatorView *act=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[act setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 20, 20)];
act.hidden=YES;

[cell.contentView addSubview:act];
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
if ([indexarr containsObject:[dataarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
{
    [act startAnimating];

    act.hidden=NO;
    return  cell;

}


return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if ([indexarr containsObject:[dataarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
{
    [mytableview reloadData];

    return;
}
[indexarr addObject:[dataarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[mytableview reloadData];

}
```

Make sure, when downloading is complete, then remove this object from indexarr....

Comment: well i did that but it still happens in the lower cells

Comment: You can check by putting breakpoint. what is a index when you scroll down.. and compare with before  when you insert into arr.

Comment: i put this code in cell for row 
if ([TODOIndecesPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell.contentView  addSubview:_redprogressBar];

    }else{
        _redprogressBar.hidden=TRUE;
    }
 but now it disappear and never come back

Comment: when it will be disappear?.. and when you tap on cell. is it visible?

Comment: it disappear just when i start scrolling from both cells and it appears just when i tap on cell

Comment: Sorry i am not understanding . why it will be disappear.Try this, put this stmt  _redprogressBar.hidden=NO; in if block.

Comment: how excactly?! look .. i'm putting this if block 
 if ([TODOIndecesPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [cell.contentView  addSubview:_redprogressBar];
        
    }else{
              _redprogressBar.hidden=TRUE;
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24759/discussion-between-mohamed-emad-hegab-and-kalpesh)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your cells are getting reused; `UITableView` will put off-screen cells into the reusable cell queue, and dequeue them for reuse if the `reuseIdentifier` matches. You should use some other data structure (e.g. `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) to track which indices/cells have already been tapped. Then, in the method you showed above, regardless of whether the cell was init-ed or dequeued, set the progress bar according to your underlying data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Here your used `UITableViewCellIdentifier` is `reuseIdentifier`. Which will work for all Cells are same type. Now your are taking once cell with progress bar. Now it will different from all cells data.

So use one more tableview cell for progress bar, or while reloading table remove the Progress bar which is exists already and add again. for this use tag for progress bar.