# UITableView mixes Cell order after Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've implemented a UITableView which works correctly on the first view, when the content is great enough to scroll and I scroll on it, it mixes up the order of the Cells.

The Array which stores the Content is a NSArray NOT a NSMutableArray.

Does anyone know this issue or does someone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the Code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableItem"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;


if (screensize.height-200 > ([fixObjects count]/3)*44) {
    tableData.scrollEnabled = NO;
} else {
    tableData.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

if ([fixObjects count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Array empty");
    cell.textLabel.text = @"No entrys found.";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.2]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:nil];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    if (position >= 0 && position < ([fixObjects count]-1)) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ m in %@", [fixObjects objectAtIndex:position], [fixObjects objectAtIndex:position+1]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fixObjects objectAtIndex:position+2]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.2]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:nil];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        position += 3;
    }
}
return cell;
```

Comment: How are you going to setup 'position' variable? Why you did not use indexPath?

Comment: Just one observation: The cellForRowAtIndexPath is going to call for each cell. It is not the appropriate place to enable or disable the scroll (due to the fixObjects.count is always the same). As a result you have to put this code e.g in the viewDidAppear

Comment: the `position`variable is necessary because i need three slots in the array for each collumn, it's initialized to 0 and it will be incremented after each collumn with 3.

`[fixObjects count]` is not always the same because I can add elements from an other view.

Comment: And you increment it for each execution of cellForRowAtIndexPath. But what about when the user is scrolling down and than up? Are you decrement it somewhere? Why you can not compute this from the actual indexPath.row, like: position = (indexPath.row * 3)

Comment: There is no decrement it will only be setted to zero again when I add new content from an other view to it and when I switch then to this view it will be redrawed completly. I think I can use indexPath, but I'm not sure if thats the solution, I will give it a try. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593059/uitableview-redraw-issue-on-scrolling?rq=1 but I dont see the analogy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we descussed in the comments, I don't really can tell you the exact solution, but the position variable is really suspicious.

Please, add the following log into the 'cell.detailTextLabel.text' code and check the the console log during the scrolling:

```
NSLog(@"cell index - %@ - position - %@ - textLabel - %@",@(indexPath.row),position, cell.textLabel.text);
NSInteger positionCandidate = indexPath.row*3; 
NSString* textCandidate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ m in %@", [fixObjects objectAtIndex:positionCandidate], [fixObjects objectAtIndex:positionCandidate+1]];
NSLog(@"cell index - %@ - posCandidate - %@ - textCandidate - %@",@(indexPath.row),positionCandidate, textCandidate);
```

I hope this can help a little!

Good luck!

Comment: In the log my position count was always +3 than yours. So I tried your positionCandidate as the objectAtIndex and I actually think it works, so you're officially my man of the Day!!! Thanks so much, spend hours before!!!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you!